# T4 Text Template - Importing and Using Own COde

Tags: c#, t4

In my `TT` file I would like to import some of my own code and use that to instantiate variables. Is this possible?

When I try "<#@ import namespace="My.Library.From.Code" #> I get back that this does not exist.

It looks like importing custom code isn't written in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-import-directive?view=vs-2019), so is this possible? Ideally I would like to import it and then call a function that I can pass into my generated file just like if it were a normal C# class file.

Comment: Did you look at the [assembly directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/t4-assembly-directive)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your class in a standard text template (Custom Tool set to TextTemplatingFileGenerator) it needs to be compiled in a separate project, and import the DLL using the <#@assembly#> directive.